# How to push the correct counter value to an HTML element in React using a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a 3 x 3 table through a simple loop as following:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const _array = [];
    let i = -1;
    for (let c = 1; c < 4; c++) {
      for (let r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
        i++;
        _array.push(
          <div
            key={`x${c}x${r}`}
            className={`x${c}x${r}`}
            onClick={() => console.log(i)}
          >
            {i}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    setArray(_array);
  }, []);
```

The `console.log(i)` in each `<div>` returns 8 although the `{i}` prints the correct number each time.

How can I code the correct `i` inside each *div* using this loop?

To reproduce you can see the full code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-snow-60q1x).

Comment: Why do you want to store React components in state?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I am producing a table of 3x3. Is there any other way I can do it? I don't want to hard code numbers obviously.

Comment: Just added an answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT store React elements in state, only data that can be rendered later.

According to the [old React docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html), `state` should only contain the minimal amount of data needed to represent your UI's state. As such, it should not contain React components. Build them in `render()` based on underlying `props` and `state`.

```js
function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const _array = [];
    let i = -1;
    for (let c = 1; c < 4; c++) {
      for (let r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
        i++;
        _array.push({ id: `x${c}x${r}`, content: i });
      }
    }
    setArray(_array);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="containter">
      <div className="game">
        {array.map((item) => (
          <button
            key={item.id}
            className={item.id}
            onClick={() => console.log(item.content)}
          >
            {item.content}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the misuse now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)